# How to read a csv file containing rows of uneven length and fix the rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Using the below code snippet on the .csv dataset threw a huge error as shown. I have tried with many suggestions but no success either.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle
#from prettytable import PrettyTable
import csv

my_udn_f = "20200914181913_18511.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(my_udn_f,sep=',', engine="python")
```

Result:

---

```
    [---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-924767287934> in <module>
      7 my_udn_f = "20200914181913_18511.csv"
      8 
----> 9 df = pd.read_csv(my_udn_f,sep=',', engine="python")

~/anaconda3/envs/kaligs_analytic1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    674         )
    675 
--> 676         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    677 
    678     parser_f.__name__ = name

~/anaconda3/envs/kaligs_analytic1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    452 
    453     try:
--> 454         data = parser.read(nrows)
    455     finally:
    456         parser.close()

~/anaconda3/envs/kaligs_analytic1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1131     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1132         nrows = _validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
-> 1133         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1134 
   1135         # May alter columns / col_dict

~/anaconda3/envs/kaligs_analytic1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, rows)
   2456             content = content\[1:\]
   2457 
-> 2458         alldata = self._rows_to_cols(content)
   2459         data = self._exclude_implicit_index(alldata)
   2460 

~/anaconda3/envs/kaligs_analytic1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _rows_to_cols(self, content)
   3111                     msg += ". " + reason
   3112 
-> 3113                 self._alert_malformed(msg, row_num + 1)
   3114 
   3115         # see gh-13320

~/anaconda3/envs/kaligs_analytic1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _alert_malformed(self, msg, row_num)
   2870 
   2871         if self.error_bad_lines:
-> 2872             raise ParserError(msg)
   2873         elif self.warn_bad_lines:
   2874             base = f"Skipping line {row_num}: "

ParserError: Expected 39 fields inline 301474, saw 41][1]
```

However, when I used the below code snippet, it runs but excludes 2 rows which I wouldn't want them excluded. Looking for more techniques to help tackle this problem at hand.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle
#from prettytable import PrettyTable
import csv

my_udn_f = "20200914181913_18511.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(my_udn_f,sep=',', engine="python", error_bad_lines=False)

Skipping line 301474: Expected 39 fields in line 301474, saw 41
Skipping line 313425: Expected 39 fields in line 313425, saw 41er code here
```

[Data File](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13wKZUIWmND3ztQAe35VxgRqbWYROSC7O?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For some reason, those two rows in column `'Request_Content_Type'`, are not properly formatted.
- There are only two, so I manually fixed them, by enclosing the offending segment in `"..."`.
- If there are more files, with additional errors, this may be something that needs to be automated.
- Also, if there is access to where the logs or being created, the log creation process should be fixed.

```py
# line 301474
1600096774,546,1600096776,220,0,641101909494671,256779102447,357909083208490,10.152.148.242,27.86.13.208,38577,80,6,internet,1024,1,212.88.127.3,212.88.127.153,"",64110177B51C3,64110177B06FF,"","","",685,431,6,5,4,249,359,78,"au-cs0.kddi.com/support/myau/fixedvalue/fixedvalue_version.xml","Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.1; ja-jp; KYV42) auCSApp/6.2.0",302,0,"",0,application/x-www-form-urlencoded,text/html,application/xhtml+xm

# add "" around the ending bit
,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded,text/html,application/xhtml+xm"

# line 313425
1600096776,206,1600096777,461,0,641101909494671,256779102447,357909083208490,10.152.148.242,111.87.221.97,40494,80,6,internet,1024,1,212.88.127.3,212.88.127.153,"",64110177B51C3,64110177B06FF,"","","",698,752,6,5,4,249,359,78,"my.au.com/rd/ac0/support/myau/fixedvalue/fixedvalue_version.xml","Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.1; ja-jp; KYV42) auCSApp/6.2.0",302,0,"",0,application/x-www-form-urlencoded,text/html,application/xhtml+xm

# add "" around the ending bit
,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded,text/html,application/xhtml+xm"

# read the file
df = pd.read_csv('20200914181913_18511.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")

# display(df.head())
   StartTimeSecond  StartTimeMilSec  EndTimeSecond  EndTimeMilSec  AssociationFlag             IMSI        MSISDN       IMEISV           MS_IP       Server_IP  MS_Port  Server_Port  IP_Protocol                 APN  Charging_Characteristics  RAT_Type Serving_Node_IP Gateway_Node_IP  CGI            SAI            RAI        TAI           ECGI  LAI  Uplink_Traffic  Downlink_Traffic  Uplink_Packets  Downlink_Packets  Protocol_Category  Application  Sub_Application  EGN_Sub_Protocol                                  URL                                                              User_Agent  Status_Code  Response_Content_Length Response_Content_Type  Request_Content_Length Request_Content_Type
0       1600096747              942     1600096749            972                0  641101003258952  256774286149  3.52854e+14    10.135.43.67    47.254.56.66    33245         6443            6            internet                      1024         1    212.88.127.5  212.88.127.157  NaN  6411017785804  64110177804FF        NaN            NaN  NaN             172                60               3                 1                 10          580              787               513                                  NaN                                                                     NaN          NaN                      NaN                   NaN                     NaN                  NaN
1       1600096749              923     1600096749            943                0  641102948752052  256774832602  3.55953e+14  10.135.224.249  41.210.187.253    64915           53           17            internet                      1024         1    212.88.127.5  212.88.127.157  NaN  64110177A45C2  64110177A0AFF        NaN            NaN  NaN              69               155               1                 1                 11          590              797                79                                  NaN                                                                     NaN          NaN                      NaN                   NaN                     NaN                  NaN
2       1600096750              181     1600096750            246                0  641101903995002  256787298917  3.57171e+14   10.130.197.55    10.120.0.138    47014         8080            6  yellopix.mtn.co.ug                       512         6   212.88.127.48  212.88.127.157  NaN            NaN            NaN  641100023  641100006C904  NaN             152               425               3                 2                  4          806             1109              2016  instagram.febb2-1.fna.fbcdn.net:443                                                                     NaN        600.0                      0.0                   NaN                     0.0                  NaN
3       1600096750              121     1600096750            185                0  641101903995002  256787298917  3.57171e+14   10.130.197.55    10.120.0.138    47004         8080            6  yellopix.mtn.co.ug                       512         6   212.88.127.48  212.88.127.157  NaN            NaN            NaN  641100023  641100006C904  NaN             152               425               3                 2                  4          806             1109              2016                  i.instagram.com:443                                                                     NaN        600.0                      0.0                   NaN                     0.0                  NaN
4       1600096743              376     1600096750            134                0  641101914219965  256778856060  3.56676e+14   10.160.38.132   34.194.71.217    56750           80            6            internet                      1024         1    212.88.127.5  212.88.127.157  NaN  64110177B3E9B  64110177B08FF        NaN            NaN  NaN             156               100               3                 2                  3          238              340              1404                  c.whatsapp.net/chat  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; WAChat/1.2; +http://www.whatsapp.com/contact)          NaN                      0.0                   NaN                     0.0                  NaN
```

### `df.iloc[301472:301474, :]`

```py
        StartTimeSecond  StartTimeMilSec  EndTimeSecond  EndTimeMilSec  AssociationFlag             IMSI        MSISDN       IMEISV           MS_IP       Server_IP  MS_Port  Server_Port  IP_Protocol       APN  Charging_Characteristics  RAT_Type Serving_Node_IP Gateway_Node_IP  CGI            SAI            RAI  TAI ECGI  LAI  Uplink_Traffic  Downlink_Traffic  Uplink_Packets  Downlink_Packets  Protocol_Category  Application  Sub_Application  EGN_Sub_Protocol                                                             URL                                                         User_Agent  Status_Code  Response_Content_Length Response_Content_Type  Request_Content_Length                                              Request_Content_Type
301472       1600096774              546     1600096776            220                0  641101909494671  256779102447  3.57909e+14  10.152.148.242    27.86.13.208    38577           80            6  internet                      1024         1    212.88.127.3  212.88.127.153  NaN  64110177B51C3  64110177B06FF  NaN  NaN  NaN             685               431               6                 5                  4          249              359                78  au-cs0.kddi.com/support/myau/fixedvalue/fixedvalue_version.xml  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.1; ja-jp; KYV42) auCSApp/6.2.0        302.0                      0.0                   NaN                     0.0  application/x-www-form-urlencoded,text/html,application/xhtml+xm
301473       1600096775              920     1600096775            923                0  641101006171954  256771861713  3.52289e+14   10.129.61.253  82.145.209.241    36193         1080            6  internet                      1024         1    212.88.127.3  212.88.127.153  NaN  64110177ACBFA  64110177A0AFF  NaN  NaN  NaN               0                40               0                 1                 16          669              922                 2                                                             NaN                                                                NaN          NaN                      NaN                   NaN                     NaN                                                               NaN
```

### `df.iloc[313423:313425, :]`

```py
        StartTimeSecond  StartTimeMilSec  EndTimeSecond  EndTimeMilSec  AssociationFlag             IMSI        MSISDN       IMEISV           MS_IP      Server_IP  MS_Port  Server_Port  IP_Protocol       APN  Charging_Characteristics  RAT_Type Serving_Node_IP Gateway_Node_IP  CGI            SAI            RAI        TAI           ECGI  LAI  Uplink_Traffic  Downlink_Traffic  Uplink_Packets  Downlink_Packets  Protocol_Category  Application  Sub_Application  EGN_Sub_Protocol                                                              URL                                                         User_Agent  Status_Code  Response_Content_Length Response_Content_Type  Request_Content_Length                                              Request_Content_Type
313423       1600096776              206     1600096777            461                0  641101909494671  256779102447  3.57909e+14  10.152.148.242  111.87.221.97    40494           80            6  internet                      1024         1    212.88.127.3  212.88.127.153  NaN  64110177B51C3  64110177B06FF        NaN            NaN  NaN             698               752               6                 5                  4          249              359                78  my.au.com/rd/ac0/support/myau/fixedvalue/fixedvalue_version.xml  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.1; ja-jp; KYV42) auCSApp/6.2.0        302.0              0.00000e+00                   NaN             0.00000e+00  application/x-www-form-urlencoded,text/html,application/xhtml+xm
313424       1600096746              725     1600096777            916                0  641101907765025  256775460010  3.54450e+14    10.129.26.81  51.15.204.181    53258          443            6  internet                      1024         6    212.88.127.3  212.88.127.153  NaN            NaN            NaN  641100032  6411000076703  NaN             134               116               2                 2                  4          250              360               430                                                              NaN                                                                NaN          NaN              4.29497e+09                   NaN             4.29497e+09                                                               NaN
```

### Automated Fix

- This is only for fixing lines that are to long, with the previously discussed issue in the `'Request_Content_Type'` row.
- This will slice off the extra elements from the end of `row`
- Those extra values will be combined into a single string, which is then appended back to `row` and saved into the correct index, `i`, in `data`
- `data` is then saved to a `'*_fixed.csv'` file.

```py
import csv

with open('20200914181913_18511.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f, open('20200914181913_18511_fixed.csv', 'w', newline='') as fixed:

    # load the rows into an object that can be updated and saved
    data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))
    
    # fix rows that are to long
    # assumes this will always be the same issue with the end of the row
    for i, row in enumerate(data):
        if i == 0:
            header_len = len(row)
        if len(row) > header_len:        
            data[i] = row[:header_len-1] + [', '.join(row[-(len(row)+1-header_len):])]
            
    writer = csv.writer(fixed, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(data)
```